# Multiplicity is not valid in Role... exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement an EF solution, but I'm getting the following run-time exceptions:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

GroupMembership_Group_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
'GroupMembership_Group_Source' in relationship 'GroupMembership_Group'. Because the
Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the 
Dependent Role must be '1'.

Gift_Membership_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 
'Gift_Membership_Source' in relationship 'Gift_Membership'. Because the Dependent Role 
refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role 
must be '1'.
```

I have the following classes:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupMembership> Memberships { get; set; }
}

public class Gift
{
    public int GiftId { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupMembership Membership { get; set; }
}

public class GroupMembership
{
    public int GroupMembershipId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Gift> Gifts { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

And the following configurations (shortened for brevity's sake):

```
public class GroupConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
{
    public GroupConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Memberships).WithRequired(x => x.Group).HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupMembershipId);
    }
}

public class GiftConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Gift>
{
    public GiftConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Membership).WithMany(x => x.Gifts).HasForeignKey(x => x.GiftId);
    }
}

public class GroupMembershipConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<GroupMembership>
{
    public GroupMembershipConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Group).WithMany(x => x.Memberships).HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupMembershipId);
        HasMany(x => x.Gifts).WithRequired(x => x.Membership).HasForeignKey(x => x.GiftId);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Additional exceptions regarding a Gift/User relationship...

```
public class Gift
{
    public int GiftId { get; set; }
    public int ClaimedByUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User ClaimedByUser { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class GiftConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Gift>
{
    public GiftConfiguration()
    {
        HasOptional(x => x.ClaimedByUser).WithOptionalPrincipal();
    }
}
```

It doesn't like the mapping.  I get `Invalid column name 'ClaimedByUser_UserId'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues in your model. If you want to configure an one-to-many relationship between `GroupMembership` and `Group`, then your model should be this way:

```
public class Group
{
  public int GroupId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<GroupMembership> Memberships { get; set; }
}

public class GroupMembership
{
    public int GroupMembershipId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Gift> Gifts { get; set; }
    public int GroupId {get;set;} //Add this FK property 
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

And your Fluent Api configuration would be:

```
public GroupConfiguration()
{
    HasMany(x => x.Memberships).WithRequired(x => x.Group).HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupId);
}
```

The problem is you are using the entity's PK as FK in an one-to-many relationship, what is wrong. The same happens in the second relationship, so do the same in the relationship between `Gift` and `GroupMembership` (add a FK property in the `Gift` entity):

```
public class Gift
{
  public int GiftId { get; set; }
  public int GroupMembershipId { get; set; } //Add this FK property
  public virtual GroupMembership Membership { get; set; }
}
```

And the configuration:

```
 HasRequired(x => x.Membership).WithMany(x => x.Gifts).HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupMembershipId);
```

Also, you don't need to repeat the configuration of both relationships in the `GroupMembershipConfiguration` class (delete them). With once it is enough.

### Update

Try with this configuration:

```
 HasOptional(x => x.ClaimedByUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(g=>g.ClaimedByUserId );
```

I think this is another one-to-many relationship because one user could be associated to one or more gifts.

Comment: Thanks!  Learning a lot.  There is a new exception I get now with another relationship if you're able to take a look.  I updated my question.